# Write file and objects to amazon s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am using amazon S3 to distribute the dynamically generated files to S3.

At a local server, I can use

```
destination = open(VIDEO_DIR + newvideo.name, 'wb+')
```

to store generated videos to the location VIDEO_DIR.newvideo.name

Is there feasible way to change VIDEO_DIR to S3 endpoint location. So the dynamically generated videos can be written to S3 server directly?

Another question is: is there any feasible way to write an object to S3 directly? For example, a `chunklet=Chunklet()`, how to write this chunklet object to S3 server directly?

I can do this first create a local file and use S3 API. For example,

```
mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
k = Key(b)
k.key = filename
k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)
k.set_contents_from_filename(filename)
k.set_acl('public-read')
```

But I want to improve the efficiency. Python is used.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`boto` library](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) to access your S3 storage. You still have to write your data to a (temporary) file first before you can send it though, as the stream writing methods have not yet been implemented.

I'd use a context manager to work around that limitation:

```
import tempfile
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def s3upload(key):
    with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=1024*10) as buffer:  # Size in bytes
        yield buffer  # After this, the file is typically written to
        buffer.seek(0)  # So that reading the file starts from its beginning
        key.set_contents_from_file(buffer)
```

Use it as a context managed file object:

```
k = Key(b)
k.key = filename
k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)

with s3upload(k) as out:
    out.write(chunklet)
```

Comment: with k.open_write() as out:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 216, in open_write
    raise BotoClientError('Not Implemented')

Comment: I had to replace `send_file()` with `set_contents_from_file()`: otherwise I would get an error 400 (Bad Request).

Answer (score 1):

Martijn's solution is great but it forces you to use the file in a context manager (you can't do `out = s3upload(…)` and `print >> out, "Hello"`). The following solution works similarly (in-memory storage up until a certain size), but works both as a context manager and as a regular file (you can do both `with S3WriteFile(…)` and `out = S3WriteFile(…); print >> out, "Hello"; out.close()`):

```
import tempfile
import os

class S3WriteFile(object):
    """
    File-like context manager that can be written to (and read from),
    and which is automatically copied to Amazon S3 upon closing and deletion.
    """

    def __init__(self, item, max_size=10*1024**2):
        """
        item -- boto.s3.key.Key for writing the file (upon closing). The
        name of the object is set to the item's name (key).

        max_size -- maximum size in bytes of the data that will be
        kept in memory when writing to the file. If more data is
        written, it is automatically rolled over to a file.
        """

        self.item = item

        temp_file = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size)

        # It would be useless to set the .name attribute of the
        # object: when using it as a context manager, the temporary
        # file is returned, which as a None name:
        temp_file.name = os.path.join(
            "s3://{}".format(item.bucket.name),
            item.name if item.name is not None else "<???>")

        self.temp_file = temp_file

    def close(self):
        self.temp_file.seek(0)
        self.item.set_contents_from_file(self.temp_file)
        self.temp_file.close()

    def __del__(self):
        """
        Write the file contents to S3.
        """
        # The file may have been closed before being deleted:
        if not self.temp_file.closed:
            self.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.temp_file

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.close()
        return False

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        Everything not specific to this class is delegated to the
        temporary file, so that objects of this class behave like a
        file.
        """
        return getattr(self.temp_file, name)
```

(Implementation note: instead of delegating many things to `self.temp_file` so that the resulting class behaves like a file, inheriting from `SpooledTemporaryFile` would in principle work. However, this is an old-style class, so `__new__()` is not called, and, as far as I can see, a non-default in-memory size for the temporary data cannot be set.)